# Facebook Like Box not showing images randomly

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

The Facebook social plugin Like Box doesn't show images from the posts in a random pattern. The images are loaded correctly but not showing in the stream. When i erase the class `"photoWrap"` from `DIV CSS` class that contains the `IMG` element the image appears correctly. The complete class name of the `DIV` element is `"_46-h photoWrap"`

Comment: Can you post your code? We can't help you without seeing what you are working with

Answer (score 3):

This is the generated code from facebook:

```
<div class="_46-h photoWrap" style="width:398px;height:204px;"><img class="_46-i img" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/p206x206/8459_10151508582178553_1981136185_n.png" style="left:-1px; top:0px;" alt="Platform Updates: We are launching two Open Graph tags to help people follow their favorite media publishers and journalists. New requirements to make it easier for us to review your app and Open Graph submissions. Learn more http://bit.ly/16Nizub" width="401" height="206"></div>
```

You generate the code from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Images used to appear in the likebox and now they are not showing up.

Unfortunately, it looks like this is entirely on Facebook's end and they need to update their like_box.php file to edit the photowrap class to remove"!important" from height and width on the class.

Let's hope someone over there reads this and resolves this issue.